# How to add scrolling feature in Xamarin.Forms to show long content in a DisplayActionSheet?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.windows

I am creating an application using **Xamarin.forms** for multi-platform mobiles. When there is an error, the application shows a **DisplayActionSheet** that explains the error. But the error content is not shown full, but just half of the sentence.

> **How to make possible to show a long content of the error in a message
>   shown by a DisplayActionSheet?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in Xamarin.Forms*. However, let's look at why.

[Here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2d9288eee6e6f197364a64308183725e7bd561f9/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Platform.cs#L107) is the code on iOS for `DisplayActionSheet`. It uses an `UIAlertController` and sets the `title` and `message` of that control. This is what you are seeing displayed. I could not find any documentation on what the actual character limit is for the `title` or `message`. It does seem to have one.

I think your best options are to create a custom dialog if you need to show very long text that is scrollable. You might also consider not showing long text like this and instead show a user-friendly message and log your error message a different way.

Note* You might be able to implement your own custom renderer for a similar method that displays a custom `UIAlertController`. However, I did see this in my research on how to customize it:

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @therealjohn , but I solved it by using by array of buttons and I added error message as the first button of array.